# Web api is not call my dependency resolver

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I've set up a very simple dependency resolver but it is not being called for my controllers.

when I hit the  HomeController GetService is called:( http:localhost:xxxx/) but (http://localhost:xxxx/api/Customers) it isn't.

In Global.asax I've put in Application_Start

```
        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new PoorMansResolver());
```

and my resolver class is

```
  public class PoorMansResolver : IDependencyResolver
    {
        static readonly ICustomerRepository CustomerRepository = new CustomerRepository();

        public object GetService(Type serviceType)
        {
            if (serviceType == typeof (CustomersController)) 
                return new CustomersController(CustomerRepository);
            else return null;
        }

        public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
        {
            return new List<object>();
        }
    }
```

Why is the resolver not being called?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you set the Resolver for both MVC4 and WebAPI?

This sets it for mvc (System.Web.Mvc):

```
DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new PoorMansResolver());
```

BUT this sets it for Web API (System.Web.Http):

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new PoorMansResolver();
```

Comment: Wow... that's horrible duplication

Comment: Haha, yep. It's the same with other parts of the stack too, including routes

Comment: @JohnnoNolan See also [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15495934/712526), for an opinion on why you shouldn't mix them.

Answer (score 1):

The dependency resolvers for WebAPi and MVC Controllers are in different namespaces. You'll have to implement a resolver for the two resolvers and assign them to mvc controllers and web api controllers seperately like below in the ninjectwebcommon.cs file

```
    private static IKernel CreateKernel()
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<Func<IKernel>>().ToMethod(ctx => () => new Bootstrapper().Kernel);
        kernel.Bind<IHttpModule>().To<HttpApplicationInitializationHttpModule>();

        RegisterServices(kernel);

        DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver());
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = new NinjectResolver(kernel);
        return kernel;
    }
```

NinjectDependencyResolver implements System.Web.Mvc.IDependencyResolver for MVC Controllers while NinjectResolver implements System.Web.Http.Dependencies.IDependencyResolver for WebApi Controllers.

Answer (score 0):

I'd be concerned with how/if you are wiring up your ControllerFactory. See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527988/cannot-inject-dependencies-into-asp-net-web-api-controller-using-unity). It's about Unity but the principle is the same.