# WebApi is throwing error - Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor

Tags: c#, ninject, asp.net-web-api2

I am trying to develop an application, through a book, in WebApi. It is a simple application but whenever I am testing this application using fiddler, it is throwing error - {"Message":"An error occurred when trying to create a controller of type 'TasksController'. Make sure that the controller has a parameterless public constructor."}. I am using ninject for dependency injection. Here is some of my code:

```
public class NinjectConfigurator
{
    public void Configure(IKernel container)
    {
        AddBindings(container);
    }

    private void AddBindings(IKernel container)
    {
        ConfigureLog4net(container);
        ConfigureNHibernate(container);
        ConfigureUserSession(container);
        ConfigureAutoMapper(container);

        container.Bind<IDateTime>().To<DateTimeAdapter>().InSingletonScope();
        container.Bind<IAddTaskQueryProcessor>().To<IAddTaskQueryProcessor>().InRequestScope();
        container.Bind<IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor>().To<AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor>().InRequestScope();
    }
```

}

```
public class TasksController : ApiController
{
    private readonly IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor _addTaskMaintenanceProcessor;

    //public TasksController() { }
    public TasksController(IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor addTaskMaintenanceProcessor)
    {
        _addTaskMaintenanceProcessor = addTaskMaintenanceProcessor;
    }

    [Route("", Name="AddTaskRoute")]
    [HttpPost]
    public Task AddTask(HttpRequestMessage requestMessage, NewTask newTask)
    {
        var task = _addTaskMaintenanceProcessor.AddTask(newTask);

        return task;
    }
}
```

I am not sure why I am getting the error. I am following all the instructions of the book. Please help!!

Comment: did you check whether that IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor  implementation has public constructor and you didn't forget to register all of it's required interfaces in IoC container?

Comment: Yes, IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor implementation has public constructor. I have placed the code in the first block which shows that I am registering the interfaces in IoC container.

Comment: public class AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor : IAddTaskMaintenanceProcessor
    {
        private readonly IAutoMapper _autoMapper;
        private readonly IAddTaskQueryProcessor _queryProcessor;

        public AddTaskMaintenanceProcessor(IAddTaskQueryProcessor queryProcessor, IAutoMapper autoMapper)
        {
            _queryProcessor = queryProcessor;
            _autoMapper = autoMapper;
        }
    }

Comment: Check the similar question at http://stackoverflow.com/a/10592456/538387 .Hope this will help you.

Comment: and make sure IAddTaskQueryProcessor implementation has public constructor too

Comment: Thank you very much Denis for the direction. The issue is gone. The code - container.Bind<IAddTaskQueryProcessor>().To<IAddTaskQueryProcessor>() is binding interface with interface and that was the issue.When I did bind the interface with the implementation then the problem was gone. The new code is container.Bind<IAddTaskQueryProcessor>().To<AddTaskQueryProcessor>(). Again thank you for the help. It was a typo.

Comment: Are you already telling the ASP.NET about the container? for example via `DependencyResolver`?

Answer (score 0):

The code - container.Bind().To() is binding interface with interface and that was the issue.When I did bind the interface with the implementation then the problem was gone. The new code is container.Bind().To(). Again thank you for the help. It was a typo.